# Finding the PGF of $Z$ using conditional expectation.

Tags: probability, generating-functions, conditional-expectation

[image]

I am working on this problem, where I am required to write down the pgf of $X$, as well as the pgf of $Y$ given $X=j$, and then using conditional expectation find the pgf of $Z$.

So far, I have
\begin{align*}
G_{X}(z)&=(pz+(1-p))^{n}\\
G_{Y|X=j}(z)&=(qz+(1-q))^{n+j}
\end{align*}

I'm new to generating functions and am having difficulty finding the pgf of $Z$. I thought I had a breakthrough when I wrote down
\begin{align*}
G_{Z}(z)&=\mathbb{E}\left(z^{Z}\right)\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(z^{n+j-Y}\right)\\
&=\frac{z^{n+j}}{G_{Y}(z)}
\end{align*}

But I'm quite sure this isn't correct as I am then required to deduce that $Z$ has the same distribution as the sum of two independent Binomial random variables. I don't know how to apply conditional expectation here. I'm sure this is a very simple problem, and I just want to understand it. Thanks for your patience and time.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}z^{n+j-Y}=z^{n+j}\mathbb{E}\left(z^{-1}\right)^{Y}=z^{n+j}G_{Y}\left(z^{-1}\right)\neq\frac{z^{n+j}}{G_{Y}\left(z\right)}$

Comment: Hint: $Z=n+X-Y$. It's the original number of infectives, plus the number of infections, minus the number of recoveries.   It is only equal to $n-j-Y$ under the condition that $X=j$.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering about that...so we'd get $G_{Z}(z)=z^{n}\frac{G_{X}(z)}{G_{Y}(z)}$

Comment: ...actually, $z^{n}G_{X}(z)G_{Y}(z^{-1})$ ?

Comment: That would be the case if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Unfortunately they are not.

Comment: But it might be true anyway... I am not sure yet.

Comment: Haha, neither am I. I'm still quite confused. Thank you for your comments, though :)

Comment: @drhab What is the significance of $z^{-1}$? Do I do calculations as usual except with $1/z$ rather than $z$?

Comment: Example. $G(z)=z^2+z^{-1}$ then $G(z^{-1})=z^{-2}+z$. I must leave  now.  Later I will have a second look.

Comment: No worries. Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the definition of a probability generating function and the Law of Iterated Expectation:

$\begin{align}
G_Y(z) & = \mathsf E(\mathsf E(z^Y\mid X))
\\ & = \mathsf E(G_{Y\mid X}(z))
\\ & = \mathsf E((qz+1-q)^{n+X})
\\ & = (qz+1-q)^n\mathsf E((qz+1-q)^{X})
\\ & = (qz+1-q)^n G_{X}(qz+1-q)
\\ & = (qz+1-q)^n \cdot\big(p(qz+1-q)+1-p\big)^n
\\ & = (qz+1-q)^n \cdot\big(pqz+1-pq\big)^n
\end{align}$

Similarly you can obtain the pgf of $Z$ by:

$\begin{align}
G_Z(z) 
& = \mathsf E(z^{n+X-Y})
\\ & = z^n\mathsf E(z^X\;\mathsf E((\tfrac 1z)^Y\mid X))
\\ & = z^n\mathsf E(z^X\;G_{Y\mid X}(\tfrac 1z))
\\ & = z^n\mathsf E(z^X\;(qz^{-1}+1-q)^{n+X}))
\\ & = (q+(1-q)z)^n\;\mathsf E((q+(1-q)z)^{X})
\\ & = (q+(1-q)z)^n\;G_X(q+(1-q)z)
\\ & = (q+(1-q)z)^n\;(p(q+(1-q)z)+1-p)^n
\\ & = (q+(1-q)z)^n\;(p(1-q)z+1-p(1-q))^n
\\ & = (qp(1-q)z+q-pq(1-q)+p(1-q)^2z^2+(1-q)z-p(1-q)^2z)^n
\\ & = (p q^2 -2 p q +p )z^2+(-2 p q^2+3 p q-p -q +1)z+(p q^2-p q+q)
\end{align}$

Comment: @drhab Thank you both for your comments. I'm very grateful. I will keep working at it with this much better perspective.

Answer (score 2):

$$G_{Z}\left(z\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left(z^{n+j-Y}\mid X=j\right)P\left(X=j\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}z^{n+j}G_{Y\mid X=j}\left(z^{-1}\right)P\left(X=j\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}z^{n+j}\left(qz^{-1}+\left(1-q\right)\right)^{n+j}P\left(X=j\right)=\left(q+\left(1-q\right)z\right)^{n}G_{X}\left(q+\left(1-q\right)z\right)$$